# Android One activity and multiple fragments with new Architecture Components

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture

Online I find mixed views about using single activity with multiple fragments, however now with the introduction of Navigation Components, it seems as if Google itself was recommending this approach.

Similarly, Google states in its material design guidelines that bottom navigation component should be visible at all times. which is easily achievable with navigation components.

However, browsing through the app store I haven't seen anyone implementing single activity, multiple fragments patterns and even Google itself doesn't show bottom navigation at all times.

Can you please advise with what should be a way of architecting Android apps, please? I am very confused with all of this. 
I am building an app for people exercising at the gym, allowing them to store their workouts and track their progress.

Comment: I think this is going to be more of an opinion answer but its just a recommendation from google, you dont have to follow it. Me personally it depends on the app, if there are a lot of screens and/or things to do I would have multiple activities otherwise your one activity is going to be cluttered with callbacks galore between your activity and fragments but thats just me

Comment: @tyczj just because you have 1 Activity doesn't mean you have to make it into a God.

Comment: `I haven't seen anyone implementing single activity, multiple fragments patterns` technically I know that [**this app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ah.budapest2017&hl=en) has 3 activities but otherwise has about 20+ fragments, except parts of the backend aren't available anymore and it was made for an event in 2017 July so parts of the app don't really work anymore. But it was 1 main fragment with 20+ fragments. Bottom navigation is visible everywhere, too. (And the ratings are "low" because people demanded features that weren't there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally feel that single activity architecture makes a lot of sense. For many reasons such as

1.) Your fragments can be reused at various places

2.) Components such as [sliding panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in say a Music app showing the song and its progress are only possible via a single activity architecture.

3.) Sharing data between fragments is much easier (with ViewModel) as Fragments are part of an activity. However, the same can't be said about activities since they are independent components. You can share data via intents but what about big objects?

All in all, there is no real downside to using Fragments in my opinion. But that doesn't mean you absolutely have to follow it at all times. Say you have a settings activity which is completely independent to other functions of your app. In this case, you can absolutely create a new activity to keep it isolated.

Personally, I try to use Fragments at all place except for features/ screens which I think are truly independent to the rest of the activities.